# "Expression of type ... doesn't conform to expected Class[] identifier expected"

Tags: hibernate, scala, spring-data-jpa

I need to use a Java class, JSONObjectUserType, in Scala. And I get errors

```
Expression of type JSONObjectUserType doesn't conform to expected Class[]
identifier expected
```

Here is the code

```
@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@TypeDefs({ @TypeDef(name = "JsonObject", typeClass =     JSONObjectUserType.class) })
class Person {
  ...
}
```

where TypeDefs is a Hibernate annotation and JSONObjectUserType is defined as

```
public class JSONObjectUserType implements UserType {
  ...
}
```

where UserType is a Hibernate library class.

How to solve this language conversion problem?

Update:
This problem is resolved by using Array in scala

```
@TypeDefs(Array(new TypeDef(name = "StringJsonObject", typeClass = classOf[JSONObjectUserType])))
```

Comment: Have you tried `classOf[JSONObjectUserType]`?

Comment: I have tried it and get "can not resolve symbol fro name & typeClass. It might be due to Array format in Scala.